# Regular expression with digits to prevent that sign don't show up

Tags: regex

How can I write a regular expression to prevent that sign doesn't show up?

I need to take only that:

```
23K
344K
1K
```

if I use regular expression

```
([1-9])K
```

I get also

```
2.3K
2.22K
```

So I don't want a dot ;)

Comment: (^[0-9]*K)$ is it correct?

Comment: `^[0-9]+K$` is quite correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[0-9]+K$
^     ^ ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI4pW9/1)

There are some things to point out:

- Anchors `^` and `$` prevent partial matches
- The `[1-9]` does not match a zero. The `[0-9]*` can match an empty string. So, either use `[0-9]+` to match 1 or more any digits, or `[1-9][0-9]*` to avoid leading zeros